# Lazy loading of images in ListView

Tags: android, lazy-loading

I know this is a widely discussed issue, but I'd like to ask a question anyway. I have lists (with BaseAdapters) in my app, all of which obtain images from the web. Now I've tried:

1) AsyncTasks in which the image is downloaded first, stored into a cache, and then displayed on the onPostExecute method. The image is obtained from the cache subsequently.

2) Nostra's [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader).

3) Fedor's [LazyList](https://github.com/thest1/LazyList). And;

4) Novoda's [ImageLoader](https://github.com/novoda/ImageLoader).

All of these methods claim to make the loading of images "lazy". But the problem is that the scrolling of my list still isn't smooth. It gets stuck and continues when the image completes loading. I've been at this for days now. Does anyone know of a good solution for this problem?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By far the easiest libaray I have used which caches images and works really well is [AQuery Image Loading](http://code.google.com/p/android-query/wiki/ImageLoading) Lib. I use it all the time for image loading and caching, really simple.

Comment: Wow, this thing is amazing!

Comment: is there any example available of loading lazy list images in Aquery?

Answer (score 1):

Try this, I hope it might help you to resolve your issue

[Example 1](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-endless)

[Example 2](http://codehenge.net/blog/2011/06/android-development-tutorial-asynchronous-lazy-loading-and-caching-of-listview-images/)