# Loading Sign before downloading Image and Setting Image on Image View

Tags: android, android-imageview

I have a listView in which I have text and an image view Now the data is coming from the service in this case text is of some bytes but due to images size imageview populate after some time . for this I want to show loading symbol in in imageview so that in time of downloading user not say that the app is not able to show images. I have implemented all listActivity and adapters concepts and its working fine but the images take time due to which the imageview part shows black area . any help

Here this I want:
[image: Loading Image]

Comment: Post your custom layout for the listview with your adapter class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Android we called it lazy list..

this will help you to understood..

1.[Lazy loading of images in ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13442920/1199602)

2.http://www.technotalkative.com/android-asynchronous-image-loading-in-listview/

For Image issue :

Change in ImageLoader class (if Using Lazy List)

```
     final int stub_id=R.drawable.ic_launcher; //change it to process image
```

Good Luck

Answer (score 1):

Place a `ProgressBar` and keep the `imageView` over the `ProgressBar`.So the progress bar is visible when there is no image in the image view. Also use [lazyList](https://github.com/thest1/LazyList) to load image.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check out Android Query. it's a library that also supports Asynchronous image loading and caching.

[Android](https://code.google.com/p/android-query/wiki/ImageLoading)